# share link on facebook,can not published.error "We are sorry.this post is no longer available, it may have been removed"

Tags: facebook, sdk

I try to share a link with Facebook SDK. It cannot be published.

Error message is

> We are sorry.this post is no longer available, it may have been removed

and it always says that.

1. I can login successfully with any account. So I think my hash key have no problem. Right?
2. It was going all right a few days before.
3. My another app B has the same code and same link to be shared with, but I can share the link successfully on B. So the code and the link should have no problem I think.

So where is the problem? I searched on Google, here, and Facebook docs, still have no clue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think i found the problem.I changed the app name before on facebook app setting.it didn't show any error until yesterday.I updated it a moment ago,now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the problem.I changed the app name before on facebook app setting.it didn't show any error until yesterday.I updated it a moment ago,now everything works fine.